# Magento 2.3.x problem in save and duplicate product

Tags: product, magento2.3

when i try to use the duplicate and save product , magento throw me  this error

> Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/Magento_2/presentation_folders_ca/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---32d_DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/Magento_2/presentation_folders_ca/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 691

what happen here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento told you that you don't have permissions to write in /var/cache folder, please check what are the permission of the /var folder.

[Overview of ownership and permissions Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html)

Comment: thx Bro, this function for me